# Agregar Bower a una aplicación ASP NET Empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, librería, bower

Estoy creando un proyecto *ASP NET MVC 5 Empty*, y estoy agregando manualmente mis referencias de *JavaScript*.

He agregado esta línea:

```
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora mis preguntas son: ¿Cómo se descargan esos paquetes, si no he agregado *Bower* al proyecto? ¿Cómo lo puedo agregar?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow quizás quiera echar un vistazo a esta pagina http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es instalar bower, los requisitos son tener instalado node, npm y git.

Una vez instalados los requisitos el comando para instalar bower es el sgte:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Luego puedes crear un archivo bower.json mediante el sgte comando:

```
bower init
```

Debes de responder las preguntas para crear un archivo bower.json personalizado.

Luego de esto puedes obtener el paquete de angular con el sgte comando:

```
bower install angular --save
```

El flag --save incluye la dependencia en tu archivo `bower.json` recién creado

Además no debes referenciar esos archivos dentro de bower_components directamente por muchos motivos, por ejemplo:

- Esa ruta ha sido definida por bower y podría cambiar en un futuro.
- Esa carpeta no debe ser desplegada ya que contiene muchos archivos posiblemente innecesarios.

Lo que deberías hacer es copiar los archivos que necesitas usando algun task runner como [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) o [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Comment: esos comandos donde debo de ejecutarlos en powershell o en el mismo ide y el tak runner tambien deberia de instalarlo?

Comment: En cualquier consola que tenga en el PATH a node, al instalar node se debería haber agregado al PATH

Comment: Tienes que ejecutar los comandos de bower al mismo nivel que el fichero html al que le inyectas el angular.min.js ( por la ruta que pones en el ejemplo).

Answer (score 5):

Así es como lo hice yo: (para VS2015, sdk 1.0.0-beta6)
*Este método NO instala bower de forma global*

NOTA: Hecho a partir de este template:

[image]

1 - Click derecho sobre el proyecto (en el explorador de soluciones), luego "Nuevo elemento" (o "New item" si el VS esta en ingles)

2 - Agregar NPM Configuration file.

[image]

3 - Editar el nuevo archivo "package.json" de modo tal que quede incluya estas 3 dependencias de desarrollo:

```
{
  "name": "nompre_projecto",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "1.6.5",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-task": "0.4.0"
  }
}
```

4 - Igual que punto 1, pero seleccionando "Grunt Configuration File".

5 - Editar Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                    layout: "byComponent",
                    cleanTargetDir: false
                }
            }
        } 
    });

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
};
```

6 - Igual que punto 1, pero seleccionando "Bower Configuration File"

7 - Editar bower.json

```
{
  "name": "SBCom",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.3",
    "angular-route": "1.4.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.4.3",
    "moment": "2.10.6",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "mocha": "2.2.5"
  }
}
```

*Con las dependencias que tu necesites*

8 - Click derecho sobre Grunfile.js y buscas "Task Runner Explorer" (no se como sera en español)

[image]

9 - Una vez abierto el "Task Runner Explorer" haces doble click sobre "bower:install". En el futuro cuando actualices o agregues un paquete bower, debes hacer lo mismo.

[image]

10 - Como en la tarea grunt se indico `targetDir: "wwwroot/lib"` debes ir ubicar el path correcto en los HTML asi:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: yo estoy usando Asp Net Mvc 5.

Comment: @rnrneverdies creo que estás confundiendo asp.net mvc 5 con asp.net 5 (que trae lo que sería asp.net mvc 6)

Comment: @rnrneverdies Éste es asp.net mvc 5: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5 y este asp.net 5: http://www.asp.net/vnext

Comment: @rnrneverdies si esta pregunta la he hecho asp .net mvc 5, no asp .net 5. y veo que toda la respuesta que me has dado es sobre asp net 5. asi como la informacion del blogpost que has puesto.  espero ahora me haya dejado entender.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz y yurivan: entendido. voy a dejar la respuesta de todos modos, con el aviso que agregue queda claro de que version se trata y sigue siendo util.